# howto disable meteor accounts user registration?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-accounts

i am using meteor accounts for login and user registration.

[image]

When a user hits the bottom line (register):

[image]

He gets redirected to the create account page:

[image]

The code behind these pages is a mixture of jade templates and javascript.

```
template(name="userFormsLayout")
  section.auth-layout
    section.auth-dialog
      +Template.dynamic(template=content)
```

It seems like the content is replaced when hitting the register link and this is as far as my knowledge goes...

I would like to prevent users from creating new accounts by either disabling the final register button on the registration page and / or disable the complete registration page.

I am also open for other solutions to prevent useers from registering.

RELATED:
[How can I set forbidClientAccountCreation to false in Meteor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32795965/how-can-i-set-forbidclientaccountcreation-to-false-in-meteor)

UPDATE:
I also tried this

```
AccountsTemplates.configure({
  forbidClientAccountCreation: true
```

but got:

```
 Error: signUp route configured but forbidClientAccountCreation set to true!
```

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't have the whole answer, but i can give you a couple pieces to get you started.

first, you can tell AccountsTemplates (AT) to use your layout. you can put this anywhere that's loaded to both client and server, e.g. lib/atConfig:

```
AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('signIn', {
    layoutTemplate: 'LoginLayout'
});
```

here's the layout template:

```
<template name="LoginLayout">
    <main>
        <div>
            {{> Template.dynamic template=main}}
        </div>
    </main>
</template>
```

in the JS, you can hide the bits of the template you don't want the user to see. here, i'm hiding the password form and a separator. you can dig into the DOM to figure out which bits you want to hide:

```
Template.LoginLayout.onRendered(function() {
    this.autorun(() => {
        if (this.subscriptionsReady()) {
            Tracker.afterFlush(() => {
                $('.at-pwd-form').remove();
                $('.at-sep').remove();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

for the server, you can check for new user attempts and reject them if they're made w/ username and password. i think this should work, but you may have to play around with it:

```
import {Meteor} from 'meteor/meteor';

Meteor.startup(() => {
    /**
     * reject registration via username/password.
     */
    Accounts.validateNewUser(function(attemptInfo) {
        if (attemptInfo && attemptInfo.services && attemptInfo.services.password) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your last Error comes from sending conflicting message to Accounts setup. You might want to remove your [route configuration](https://guide.meteor.com/accounts.html#useraccounts-customizing-routes) for the signup page?

Comment: How can i make the signUp route config dependend to the meteor settings.json config or the ForbidClientAccountCreation?